# Measuring program runtime in python

Tags: python, performance, loops, time

I have a program say:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    for p in xrange(10):
        print i, p
```

I would like to be able to print the time in milliseconds that the program took to execute at the end of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a small snippet that could allow you to measure the elapsed time using a context manager. Have a look at https://github.com/BaltoRouberol/timer-context-manager

Example:

```
from timer import Timer

with Timer() as t:
    # Some code we want to time

print t.elapsed_ms  # elapsed time, in milliseconds
```

It uses `timeit.default_timer` (a platform specific timer function :`time.time` for Unix platforms and  `time.clock` for Windows platforms) to measure the wall clock time of the block.

Answer (score 4):

Run your program with `python -m timeit -s 'import my_module' 'my_module.do_stuff()'` to see running time information.

As per the `timeit` [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html), just rolling your own is a tiny bit tricky, so it's provided for you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it inside your python code although I prefer the method by @Julian, just providing this as an alternative:

```
from timeit import timeit

def foo():
    for i in xrange(10):
        for p in xrange(10):
            print i, p

print timeit(setup='from __main__ import foo', stmt='foo()') # returns float of seconds taken to run
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the `time.clock()` function (http://docs.python.org/library/time.html)

Comment: `timeit` is best for measuring runtime

Comment: How did I not know this existed? I've always made my own. Thanks, and +1 for the other answer.